# Configuration Postfix with two domains

Tags: linux, email, virtual, postfix-mta

I want receive email by admin@xxx.pl and admin@yyy.pl I tried to do this but it show warning:

```
root@debian2008:/home/wojtek# postalias hash:/etc/postfix/virtual
postalias: warning: /etc/postfix/virtual, line 1: name must be local
postalias: warning: /etc/postfix/virtual, line 2: name must be local
```

It's my file /etc/postfix/virtual:

```
admin@xxx.pl :    root
admin@yyy.pl :    root
```

And /etc/postfix/main.cf:

```
myorigin = /etc/mailname


smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP 
biff = no


append_dot_mydomain = no
readme_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix
smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
smtpd_use_tls=yes
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache

virtual_alias_domains = xxx.pl,yyy.pl
virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual



mail_owner = postfix
myhostname = debian2008
mydomain = yyy.pl
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
mydestination = localhost, debian2008, xxx.pl, yyy.pl
relayhost = 
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8


mailbox_command = 
mailbox_size_limit = 50000000
recipient_delimiter = 
inet_interfaces = all
html_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix/html
inet_protocols = all
home_mailbox = Maildir/
mail_spool_directory = /home/
```

admin@yyy.pl works but admin@xxx.pl not. How I can do this? What's the problem with warning?

P.s Sorry for bad english but i'm polish

Comment: This question should probably be moved to Server Fault.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `postmap` to create your alias map, not `postalias`, and then your `virtual` shouldn't use colons as separators:

```
admin@xxx.pl        root
admin@yyy.pl        root
```

Other then this, it should work.